# Ububtu Windows 10 grub rescue

Tags: grub2, windows

I see that similar questions have been asked but I have a twist. Have 1TB drive with Windows 10 installed, added an old 60mb dive to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After install, on start up the 1TB Windows 10 drive would not load because of grub rescue. Ubuntu loaded from the 60mb drive, but when switching drives on restart I get the errors in the image below. Note that I have attached a shot of the computer drives using Linux Mint, the Linux Bistro I prefer.Just wanted to check out Ubuntu, but what a mistake. Never had this problem before. Any Ideas how I can save my Windows drive or at least the files? I would like to run the drive like it was this morning.enter image description here
[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc8UL.jpg)
[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcwvF.jpg)
[Screen3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU73S.jpg)

Comment: Try using Boot Repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair to fix the grub loader to load up Windows.  Also, I would recommend that if you're going to have dual boot with Linux and Windows 10 to disable the Fast Boot option in Windows so that you don't end up with the hibernated drive error in Linux when trying to mount.  https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

Comment: Here is another Screen shot showing the partitions on the 1TB Windows drive. Did't know if that would help. I'll check out theBoot-Repair once i get some rest and make sense of it. Thanks for the feedback. [link] {file:///home/linux/Desktop/20180203_223300.jpg}

Comment: Thank you Terrance. I followed your suggestion, used the instruction from the link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and booted from my original Ubuntu dvd ISO, entered the commands supplied, downloaded and launched Boot-Repair, restarted and the Windows 10 disk was up and running again, performed a Windows disk check and all looks good.

Comment: You're very welcome!  =)

Answer (score 0):

Changing your bootloader back to Windows' MBR should enable you to boot Windows as normal.

Try using Lilo.
Install Lilo by entering in the Ubuntu terminal

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
```

and once it is done installing enter this command to restore the windows boot manager:

```
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

Now when you boot the 1TB drive it should load Windows as normal.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Aaron, this sounds like a good option as well. Fortunately the previous suggestion worked using Boot Repair. If it had not, I surely would have tried Lilo.

Comment: @MakinBoxes Perfect - the main thing is that you got it working. And probably you know this, but it may be better for you to try out an OS using a virtual machine rather than actually installing it - it saves you the headache.